# absolute strength of the magnetic field : Android

Tags: android

Similar to GPS Status application in android I want to get the "absolute strength of the magnetic field" and "theoretical strength". I am able to get the theoretical strength using `GeomagneticField` `getFieldStrength()` method .

But I am not sure how to get the "absolute strength of the magnetic field" from sensors.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, may i know what you mean by "absolute strength" of the magnetic field?

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for an absolute value of the magnetic field strength, you could simply calculate it as follows:

```
private final SensorEventListener mySensorListener = new SensorEventListner() {
   public void onSensorChange(SensorEvent event) {
       sensorRead = event.value;
       int sensorType = event.sensor.getType();

       if(sensorType = Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
          mag = sensorRead;
          magAbsVal = Math.sqrt(mag[0]*mag[0] + mag[1]*mag[1] + mag[2]*mag[2]);
       }
   }
}
```

This will give you the absolute uT value read from the magnetometer. If you are looking for a percentage value, you can use `percentMag = largestMag/magAbsVal` .

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the value of largetstMag?